# Freezes in large compiles and archive extractions (18.04)

Tags: 18.04, thinkpad, compiler

My [Thinkpad T440p](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t440p/20aw/20aws1a600?linkTrack=Homepage%3ABody_Search%20Products&searchType=5&keyWordSearch=20AWS1A600) freezes and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS stops when I compile large projects in IDEA. Unzipping the archive of a new version also results in the system getting stuck after some time. This problem repeats every time when trying to unzip the archive or compile a large project (even in terminal).

The OS is installed on an SSD and SMART data seems OK.

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Intel 53x and Pro 2500 Series SSDs
Device Model:     INTEL SSDSC2BW240H6
Serial Number:    CVTR5502016D240CGN
LU WWN Device Id: 5 5cd2e4 14ca4b872
Firmware Version: RG21
User Capacity:    240 057 409 536 bytes [240 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Sep  5 19:33:38 2019 MSK
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 5860) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7f) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Abort Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  58) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   4) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x0025) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
  9 Power_On_Hours_and_Msec 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6540h+00m+00.000s
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1393
170 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0033   088   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       34
183 SATA_Downshift_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   100   100   090    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0032   041   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       41 (Min/Max 15/57)
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       34
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
225 Host_Writes_32MiB       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       614620
226 Workld_Media_Wear_Indic 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       65535
227 Workld_Host_Reads_Perc  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       44
228 Workload_Minutes        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       65535
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0033   088   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   038   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
241 Host_Writes_32MiB       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       614620
242 Host_Reads_32MiB        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       487379
249 NAND_Writes_1GiB        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       220231

SMART Error Log not supported

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Aborted by host               00%      6540         -
# 2  Short offline       Aborted by host               00%      6540         -
# 3  Extended offline    Aborted by host               00%      6540         -
# 4  Extended offline    Aborted by host               00%      6540         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

And this is my laptop's parameters:

```
System:    Host: WS-5241 Kernel: 5.2.11-050211-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: LENOVO product: 20AWS1A600 v: ThinkPad T440p serial: N/A
           Mobo: LENOVO model: 20AWS1A600 v: 0B98401 WIN serial: N/A
           UEFI [Legacy]: LENOVO v: GLET74WW (2.28 ) date: 10/21/2014
Battery    BAT0: charge: 34.7 Wh 99.9% condition: 34.7/56.2 Wh (62%)
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i3-4000M (-MT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB
           clock speeds: max: 2400 MHz 1: 1064 MHz 2: 1290 MHz 3: 1286 MHz 4: 1150 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) driver: i915 Resolution: 1366x768@60.00hz, 1280x1024@60.02hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Mobile version: 4.5 Mesa 19.0.8
Audio:     Card-1 Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-2 Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k5.2.11-050211-generic
Network:   Card-1: Intel Ethernet Connection I217-LM driver: e1000e
           IF: enp0s25 state: down mac: 68:f7:28:0a:8e:9e
           Card-2: Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235 driver: iwlwifi
           IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: 08:d4:0c:1e:fa:eb
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 748.2GB (20.6% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: INTEL_SSDSC2BW24 size: 240.1GB
           ID-2: /dev/sdb model: ST500LM021 size: 500.1GB
           ID-3: USB /dev/sdc model: Transcend_8GB size: 8.0GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 220G used: 144G (70%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 55.0C mobo: 0.0C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: 3061
Info:      Processes: 285 Uptime: 15 min Memory: 2977.8/15729.0MB Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.56
```

What else I can check to resolve this error?

1. My swap size is: 
   2097148(2Gb)
   but I believe that error is not related to lack of RAM size. Because I have 16 Gb of RAM and when I start extract archive it's full for ~ 3 Gb and it doesn't increase speedily.
2. With 7z I have similar results. Working til 35%-40% and stuck completely.
3. I've booted in recovery mode and command tar -zxvf ***tar.gz(tested archive) completed well. I suppose that I got some bug after updates for gnome environment.

Comment: Just for a test, I would suggest enlarging your swap to completely rule that out as a possible issue. Once you've done that, if it still fails, I'd remove swap from /dev/sda entirely and put it on /dev/sdb your HDD, then try large ZIP file extractions again. Please check back and post your results in your question with [edit] as you did before.

Comment: Your processor is at 55 degrees C with, I think, light load on the CPUs, based on their clock frequencies. Suggest to use turbostat (linux-tools-common package) to observe processor package temp leading up to one of these events. Do: `sudo turbostat --quiet --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,GFXWatt,IRQ --interval 15`. Try an interval of 5 seconds, if needed. Also examine `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/kern.log` for clues.

Comment: Thanks Doug! In syslog I've found some error which appeared before stuck. It was from forticlient (Fortitray.desktop[3000]: message repeated 18 times: [ Received message {"fmon_status":"ON"}]). Then I removed forticlient and for now everything works fine.