# Ubuntu 19.10 freezes when running a maven build

Tags: kernel, java, freeze

kernel version: 5.3.0-51-generic

Ubuntu version: 19.10

Java version: Open JDK 11

Ubuntu 19.10 Laptop freezes in the middle of a maven build. The same thing happens sometimes for Gradle builds as well. Once the machine freezes, I can't click anywhere or switch windows. The only option is the hard-reset. These are the last few syslog lines just before the crash. Any help is appreciated.

```
May 15 14:14:51 asanka-h Fortitray.desktop[2360]: check_message_call_back
May 15 14:14:51 asanka-h Fortitray.desktop[2360]: message repeated 5 times: [ check_message_call_back]
May 15 14:14:51 asanka-h Fortitray.desktop[2360]: update icon
May 15 14:14:51 asanka-h Fortitray.desktop[2360]: check_message_call_back
May 15 14:14:53 asanka-h Fortitray.desktop[2360]: Received message {"fmon_status":"ON"}
May 15 14:14:56 asanka-h fctsched[982]: cat: write error: Broken pipe
May 15 14:14:56 asanka-h Fortitray.desktop[2360]: Received message {"fmon_status":"ON"}
May 15 14:15:14 asanka-h Fortitray.desktop[2360]: message repeated 6 times: [ Received message {"fmon_status":"ON"}]
May 15 14:15:15 asanka-h fctsched[982]: cat: write error: Broken pipe
May 15 14:15:17 asanka-h Fortitray.desktop[2360]: Received message {"fmon_status":"ON"}
May 15 14:15:35 asanka-h Fortitray.desktop[2360]: message repeated 6 times: [ Received message {"fmon_status":"ON"}]
May 15 14:15:35 asanka-h fctsched[982]: cat: write error: Broken pipe
May 15 14:15:38 asanka-h Fortitray.desktop[2360]: Received message {"fmon_status":"ON"}
May 15 14:15:41 asanka-h Fortitray.desktop[2360]: Received message {"fmon_status":"ON"}
May 15 14:15:42 asanka-h slack.desktop[2167]: [05/15/20, 14:15:42:142] info: Store: SET_SYSTEM_IDLE active
May 15 14:15:42 asanka-h slack.desktop[2167]: [05/15/20, 14:15:42:156] info: [DESKTOP-SIDE-EFFECT] Update from desktop for keys  ["app"]
May 15 14:15:44 asanka-h Fortitray.desktop[2360]: Received message {"fmon_status":"ON"}
May 15 14:15:53 asanka-h Fortitray.desktop[2360]: message repeated 3 times: [ Received message {"fmon_status":"ON"}]
May 15 14:15:55 asanka-h fctsched[982]: cat: write error: Broken pipe
May 15 14:15:56 asanka-h Fortitray.desktop[2360]: Received message {"fmon_status":"ON"}
May 15 14:16:08 asanka-h Fortitray.desktop[2360]: message repeated 4 times: [ Received message {"fmon_status":"ON"}]
May 15 14:16:10 asanka-h Fortitray.desktop[2360]: check_message_call_back
May 15 14:16:10 asanka-h Fortitray.desktop[2360]: message repeated 4 times: [ check_message_call_back]
```

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: @guiverc I ran a dist-upgrade. So now I have ubuntu 19.10 and still the same problem. I updated the question.

Comment: `dist-upgrade` doesn't upgrade to a new release.

Comment: Removing forticlient worked for me. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171109/freezes-in-large-compiles-and-archive-extractions-18-04